# Reading SQL Server .sqlaudit Files Stored in S3

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, aws, audit

I set up an audit in SQL Server that saves audit logs (.sqlaudit files) to RDS, which we then copy over to S3 using a standard process. All of the documentation I can find on reading these audit files uses the following query to read them from RDS:

```
SELECT *
FROM msdb.dbo.rds_fn_get_audit_file
('D:\rdsdbdata\SQLAudit\transmitted\*.sqlaudit'
,default,default)
```

RDS has an option setting called RETENTION_TIME for SQL Server Audit which allows you to specify a maximum of 840 hours before the files are removed from the RDS instance. I need to to be able to read the audit files for a longer period of time, so I am looking for a way to query the audit files in S3 instead, where they are retained.

One way may be to use sys.fn_get_audit_file, but I cannot do this with any user attached to this server that my organization has access to, even the admin user. None of the users have proper permissions for this and I don't see any way they can be granted.

With the .sqlaudit files sitting in the S3 bucket, how could I go about reading the files? Perhaps S3 Select could do it somehow, or maybe there's another obvious solution I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the format of the audit file you could query it directly with [AWS Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/faqs/) from S3 if it’s a supported format. If the format isn’t directly supposed by AWS Athena you can use [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/faqs/) to do a transformation as some of the answers on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55284580/how-to-query-nested-xml-file-in-aws-athena-via-glue) suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have read-access into S3....

There are ways (e.g. CloudBerry Drive, TntDrive) to mount S3 as a drive letter.

If you had a server with S3 mounted as a drive letter (for all users), which also hosted an Instance of SQL Server, you should be able to query the files using sys.fn_get_audit_file().

It wouldn’t be the same as querying the files ***in*** S3, because each file would need to be downloaded in the background before being opened, but it might be viable depending on the file size and network throughput. A server in AWS 'close' to S3 would be advantageous.